# How can I fill in the outside of a path?

Tags: html, canvas

I am able to draw these letters using a path. But what I want to do is use that path and fill in what the red image shows instead of filling in the letters.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function mattes_draw_letter(x, y, width, height, letter, position)
{
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  canvas.style.top = y + "px";
  canvas.id = "canvas_opening_" + position;
  canvas.style.zIndex = 5;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.style.left = x + "px";
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#bfbfbf';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(letter[0] * width, letter[1] * height);
  for (i = 0; i < letter.length; i+=2)
  {
    if (typeof letter[i+3] !== 'undefined')
    {
      ctx.lineTo(letter[i+2] * width, letter[i+3] * height);
    }
  }
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();


  $("#mattes").append(canvas);

  canvas.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {drop(event, this);}, false); 
  canvas.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {allowDrop(event);}, false); 
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {photos_add_selected_fid(this);}, false);
}
```

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your html code? A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Just fill the boxes with red color before drawing the letters in gray.
I was able to do this by adding two lines of code in your code.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

Put these two lines between the lines:

```
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
```

and

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#bfbfbf';
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're starting the existing letters otherwise (as @Chirag64 says), you can just draw the red rectangles first and then draw the letters on top).

You can use canvas compositing to "draw behind" existing content.

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/695dY/

[image]

In particular the `destination-over` compositing mode will draw new content **behind** existing content (new content is only drawn where the existing content is transparent).

```
context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
```

Assuming the HOPE characters are drawn over a transparent background you can add red rectangles behind the HOPE characters like this:

```
// draw red rectangles **behind** the letters using compositing

ctx.fillStyle="red";

ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";

for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    ctx.fillRect(i*62+16,13,50,88);  // your x,y,width,height depend on your artwork
}
```